# Android perfil de desenvolvimento (Profile)

Tags: java, android

Estava dando uma olhada aqui e ainda não encontrei se existe uma forma, acredito que vocês também passam por isso.

Quando estamos desenvolvendo um aplicativo que utiliza algum serviço, temos em algum lugar do nosso código o endereço do servidor que vamos utilizar para enviar/receber os dados que geralmente, quando estamos desenvolvendo, apontamos para nosso IP Local ou servidor
de testes, e quando vamos colocar em produção vamos lá no código e alteramos o(s) endereço(s) como no código abaixo:

```
/* Exemplo */
Class Servidor{
   public String final SERVIDOR = "http://192.168.1.8:8080"; //DESENVOLVIMENTO
/* public String final SERVIDOR = "http://servidorproducao.com.br"; //DESENVOLVIMENTO */

}
```

No Spring eu uso o `spring.profiles.active`  que defino como dev onde tenho os arquivos já configurados com todos os endereços de desenvolvimento que basta alterar uma variável de ambiente ou no próprio `web.xml` para trocar toda a configuração automaticamente ou até mesmo em tempo de execução.

Existe algo similar que faça isso automaticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Java pode ser feito um arquivo com pares de chave-valor e carregado usando a classe [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

No código é necessário fazer a carga desse arquivo de propriedades e partindo dessa instancia, onde foi carregado o arquivo, é possível carregar os valores partindo de uma chave.

Comment: fmsedrez, to pensando que a única maneira de fazer de forma mais amigável vai ser esta mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu gosto de tratar essa questão de perfis no build, usando buildTypes do gradle.

No meu caso normalmente meus aplicativos tem 3 builds diferentes:

- Dev apontando para servidor de desenvolvimento
- Staging apontando para o servidor de staging/pre-produção
- Release, que é o build assinado apontando para o ambiente de produção

no build.gradle do seu aplicativo, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://api.aplicativo.com/api/v1\""
        }

        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            zipAlign true
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://dev.aplicativo.com/api/v1\""
        }

        staging.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        staging {
            packageNameSuffix ".stating"
            versionNameSuffix "-staging"
            zipAlign true
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://staging.aplicativo.com/api/v1\""
        }
    }
}
```

E no código, apenas acesso via a classe BuildConfig

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(BuildConfig.BASE_URL + "/clients/");
```

Note que eu também costumo ter package names diferentes para cada tipo de build

com.example.app -> release
com.exemple.app.debug -> debug
com.exemple.app.stating -> staging

Dessa forma posso ter diversas versões do app instaladas no meu smartphone/emulador, cada uma apontando para um ambiente diferente.

Answer (score 0):

No Android você tem a opção de usar `ActivityPreferences`, para configurar o modo como seu aplicativo funciona.

[Tutorial Activity Preferences](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/)

Comment: **Bem vindo!** Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Por isso, e porque é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta?

Comment: Pensei em utilizar assim mais seria mais uma tela para o usuario acessar e fazer "caca", no caso do build já fica implicito que o apk é produção ou de teste sem ter opção do usuário alterar.